# What was the first ever BIP 16 transaction? (Read: Not BIP 13)

Tags: p2sh, blockchain-explorer

I'm having a very difficult time finding the first-ever P2SH transaction on the blockchain. I do not have a query tool to answer this question myself, sadly.

All internet searches result in this answer:

[9c08a4d78931342b37fd5f72900fb9983087e6f46c4a097d8a1f52c74e28eaf6](https://mempool.space/tx/9c08a4d78931342b37fd5f72900fb9983087e6f46c4a097d8a1f52c74e28eaf6)

(Block 170,052 | March 3, 2012)

But as [bitcoin wiki points out](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pay_to_script_hash#:%7E:text=342ftSRCvFHfCeFFBuz4xwbeqnDw6BGUey%20is%20a%20Bitcoin%20address,good%20example%20to%20understand%20P2SH.), this is the first BIP 13 transaction (first address beginning with a "3") and the P2SH soft-fork was not yet active, since it occurred on April 1st 2012.

I think this means the first legitimate P2SH transaction would be the first "3" address occurring on or after April 1st, 2012. Using vague tools I am under the impression that such a transaction occurred around April 7 or 8, 2012. However I am unable to dig deeper without manually searching every block on those dates.

I'm surprised this information is so hard to find since it seems like such an important moment in bitcoin's history. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Help greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used Blockchair to only [search for transaction outputs of type P2SH](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/outputs?s=block_id(asc)&q=type(scripthash),time(2012-03-11..),block_id(173805..)#f=transaction_hash,index,value,value_usd,recipient,is_spent,spending_transaction_hash,spending_time,spending_value_usd,cdd,type,block_id,time), and restricted results to blocks after the activation height of block 173 805. I also checked against any time after March 11th and got the same result.

The first transaction that sent funds to a P2SH output appears to be
[2597f4819e1902750b9e1fa1515df22bbf14f3a78a2b82aa7d62a8109d83289d](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/2597f4819e1902750b9e1fa1515df22bbf14f3a78a2b82aa7d62a8109d83289d) in block 174 717 on 2012-04-08 (UTC).

Then, I further restricted the search to only permit [*spent* outputs of type P2SH sorted by ascending spending block height after 173 805](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/outputs?s=spending_block_id(asc)&q=type(scripthash),time(2012-03-11..),block_id(173805..),is_spent(true),spending_block_id(173805..)#f=transaction_hash,index,value,value_usd,recipient,is_spent,spending_transaction_hash,spending_time,spending_value_usd,cdd,type,block_id,time,spending_block_id) to find the first P2SH output that was spent in transaction [e5779b9e78f9650debc2893fd9636d827b26b4ddfa6a8172fe8708c924f5c39d](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/e5779b9e78f9650debc2893fd9636d827b26b4ddfa6a8172fe8708c924f5c39d) at block height 174 719.

Comment: Ah I was unaware of the Blockchair tool. Thank you so much!